# mail::sendmail client not authenticated error

Tags: perl, email, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to use the Mail::Sendmail package to send a mail. Yet I am getting this error:

> MAIL FROM: error (530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to
>   send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM)

I suspect this has something to do with my `santaclaus@christmas.com` mail ?

```
    use Mail::Sendmail qw(sendmail %mailcfg);
unshift @{$Mail::Sendmail::mailcfg{'smtp'}} , 'smtp.office365.com:587';
%mail = ( To => 'existingmail@outlook.com',
          From => 'santaclaus@christmas.com',
          Message => "Time for surprises and gifts is approaching..."
);

sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;
print "OK. Log says:\n", $Mail::Sendmail::log;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that smtp.office365.com requires SMTP `AUTH` command (SMTP Authentication) to accept email for sending.
`Mail::Sendmail` **DOES NOT** support SMTP authentication.

http://search.cpan.org/~mivkovic/Mail-Sendmail-0.79/Sendmail.pm

> **LIMITATIONS**
>   [...]
>   No suport for the SMTP AUTH extension.